# Subversion (Tortoise) Include only specific file types

Tags: svn

I have a folder in my web app where it stores images. These are "runtime" files added during app workflow and shouldn't be committed to source control.

There is a PHP file in this folder which does need to be committed.

How can I tell Subversion (TortoiseSVN) to add this folder and the `.php` file only. i.e. only include `.php` files and exclude all others?

Answer (score 0):

You only add that file. In windows for example:

Right click over the folder which contains the .php file, select TortoiseSVN -> Add, once you do that another windows will display with all the contents of the folder you are trying to add, deselect everything but the file you want to subversion, click "ok" and commit. Now only that file (the one you selected) inside the folder will be added when you commit (It will ignore all the others and only commit the changes made to that particular file).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From The Tortoise SVN menu you can exclude items going towards the repository using a specific pattern eg if you want to exclude images add jpg, or a folder named images then add the name images in the exclude items.